# Hard Disk Upgrade

Tags: hard-drive, disk-image

I want to upgrade my laptop hard disk but take an image of my current drive and make the new one exactly the same and bootable so that basically I just have a bigger hard disk.

Can this be done - an image and then make the new one bootable so that it is just seamless in transition ?

Sorry, I dont much about this stuff - can a local laptop shop do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re comfortable with some command line, you can use dd or a variant of dd. It’s a common program that can make an exact duplicate of the disk.

Otherwise, you can use clonezilla or rescuezilla. Rescuezilla is slightly more user friendly because of its graphical user interface. If you only have 1 drive then you must boot from an external source and use these options as the volume you are trying to clone must be unmounted first.

If you’re absolutely dependent on a program, then you can use macrium reflect, or easeus todo backup.